# Redshift table column name auto convert to lowercase issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am facing an issue while fetching the data via query from a redshift table. For example:

```
table name:   test_users
column names: user_id, userName, userLastName
```

Now while creating the `test_users` table it converts the capital letter of the `userName` column to `username` and similar with `userLastName` which will be converted to `userlastname`.

I have found the way to convert the all columns to capital or in lowercase, but not in the way to get it as it is.

Comment: You must use double quotes around the column names in SQL to prevent case folding, e.g. `"userName"`. However, I strongy recommend that you don't do that and stick with lower case names. Otherwise there is a world of pain waiting.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 

yes i have tried in double quotes as well. But that did not worked in POSTGRES SQL

I understand your concern, but i am just working on some of previous things, which had used this format. So just trying to sort out that issue first.

Comment: Using double quotes definitely works in PostgreSQL. You'll have to post some SQL error messages to make clear what your problem is.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe

Here is an example of create table. If you try to use this query with or without quotes. It never sorted out the issue.




CREATE TABLE users  (
id FLOAT4 NOT NULL,
test_id VARCHAR(100) encode zstd,
user_id VARCHAR(50) encode zstd,
userName VARCHAR(50) encode zstd,
userLastName VARCHAR(50) encode zstd,
primary key (id)
)diststyle key DISTKEY(id) SORTKEY(test_id);

Comment: There is no `encode`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, AWS Redshift does not support case-sensitive identifiers at the time of writing (Feb 2020).  And, while Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, AWS has heavily modified it to the point where many assumptions that would be correct for PostgreSQL 8 are not correct for Redshift.

The documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html explicitly states that it downcases identifiers.  The relevant paragraph is below, with the critical sentence bolded:

> Names identify database objects, including tables and columns, as well as users and passwords. The terms name and identifier can be used interchangeably. There are two types of identifiers, standard identifiers and quoted or delimited identifiers. Identifiers must consist of only UTF-8 printable characters. **ASCII letters in standard and delimited identifiers are case-insensitive and are folded to lowercase in the database.** In query results, column names are returned as lowercase by default. To return column names in uppercase, set the describe_field_name_in_uppercase configuration parameter to true.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve case:

- `SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;`

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html

To force returned uppercase fields (for anyone else curious):

- `SET describe_field_name_in_uppercase TO on;`

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_describe_field_name_in_uppercase.html